# Javascript menu moving left and exposing gap on right side of screen in android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a very basic menu for my site for  when it is viewed on mobile devices. It functions exactly as intended in all browsers. Like I said, it functions in all browsers. It toggles open and toggles closed the divs. The problem is that in the default Android browser when you open the menu for the first time it moves left and exposes a large gap on the right side of the menu. It is like the menu is shrinking in width. If I close and re-open the menu the menu will have the 100% width like it is supposed to. It does not do this in Firefox Android browser. Just the default browser. Aside from the width being smaller everything else is fine

The menu often hangs in a way some times. When you close the menu container that is associated with the toggle things inside the container are left "hanging" on the screen." Pieces of divs are left on the screen. Could this have to do with slideToggle? Would it go away if I simply used Toggle?

Here is my js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#mobilemenu").hide();
                $("#mobilemenu-drop").show();

            $('#mobilemenu-drop').click(function(){
            $("#mobilemenu").slideToggle();
            return false;
            });

        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#cats").hide();
                $(".show_cats").show();

            $('#mobilemenu-catdrop').click(function(){
            $("#cats").slideToggle();
            return false;
            });

        });
```

here is my html

```
    <header>
        <h1>title</h1>

    <span class="right">
        <div id="mobilemenu-drop">
            click
        </div>
    </span>
</header>

<div id="mobilemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="mobilemenu-catdrop">
        <span>Second drop</span>
    </div>

    <div id="cats">cats
        drop content
    </div>
</div>
```

The css for the menu contaiiners is this

```
#mobilemenu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #2e97de;
    border-top: #8dc8f2 1px solid;
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue also.

The way I worked around it (and has worked so far) is to set the width @ 102%, and turn overflow-x:hidden;

This would extend it off the right side (Since browsers by default work from left to right), but if it is extending off the left, you may need to set margin-left:0px; or even -1px;